# Click button doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code successfully works in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox.

```
<div class=" form-group text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-4">
      <img src="model/capcha.php" id="capImage"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input name="captcha_code" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="refreshbtn" >Click Here refresh</button>.
</div>
<script>
  $('#refreshbtn').click(function () {
    $('#capImage').attr('src','model/capcha.php');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: There's no reason for that to work in Chrome but not in FF. Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: duplicate happens to also be the exact same src (captcha).

Comment: @Jamiec That was a great needle to find in this haystack

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan something in my mind thought FF handled changing the src slightly differently from chrome. Google came through.

Comment: thank you so much , it working now :)